# Tiny Android app to control which other apps can rotate the screen

Tags: android, display, touchscreen, rotate

There are scores of Android apps that allow the user to control whether or not specific apps can rotate the screen.

Most of them, even if they have a small APK size, occupy 10+ MB of RAM all the time.

I'm looking for a tiny Android app that allows the user to specify which other apps can rotate the screen.  I'm okay if it operates as *"opt-in"* or  *"opt-out"* when specifying which apps can rotate.

The app **must** use less than 10MB of RAM in the background.  Less is definitely better.

The app can require root privileges, and can also require the Xposed Framework.  It must be compatible with Android KitKat.

Any price is acceptable.